# Deutsche Bezeichnungen für Begriffe aus der Typtheorie

Tags: mathematics, nomenclature

In der Informatik hat man Variablen verschiedenen *Typs*, wie z.B. `Bool` (Typ von `True`), `String` (Typ von `"abc"`) oder `Maybe`. Manche Programmiersprachen unterscheiden neben Typen jedoch auch *kinds*, sozusagen Typen von Typen. Z.B. ist in Haskell das kind von `Bool` `*` und das von `Maybe` `* -> *`. In wenigen Sprachen geht man noch weiter und definiert *sorts*, Typen von kinds, also quasi Typen von Typen von Typen.

Ich frage mich, ob es neben der im Englischen angewandten Nomenklatur *type*, *kind*, *sort* auch allgemein anerkannte Bezeichnungen für Typen, Typen von Typen und Typen von Typ-Typen gibt. Wenn es diese nicht gibt, hat jemand eine Idee, wie man diese nennen könnte, ohne häßliche Anglizismen verwenden zu müssen?

Comment: Bitte dann auch gleich die Entsprechungen in niederländisch, klingonisch und sonstwas. Die Anglizismen sind nicht hässlicher, als eine überflüssige Übersetzung in eine andere Sprache und sollte im wissenschaftlichen Sprachgebrauch unterbleiben. Bloß weil du die Worte kennst, wird die Bedeutung kein bisschen klarer.

Comment: Kann bitte der, der die Frage herabgestimmt hat sich erklären? Das ist nicht sehr produktiv, einfach ohne Kommentar sowas zu tun.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht ganz, welches Problem besteht die etablierten Fachbegriffe zu verwenden. Die Einschätzung "häßlich" ist hier recht subjektiv, mal sehen wie "schön" eine deutsche Übersetzung werden wird. Ob der Leser den neu geschöpften übersetzten Begriff ohne Erklärung auch mit dem englischen Fachbegriff in Verbindung bringt ist ebenfalls fraglich.

Comment: Offenbar sind Anglizismen "häßlicher" als Latinismen oder Gräzismen, sonst würde man wohl von der "Sorteneinteilung" und nicht der "Typtheorie" sprechen müssen, oder?

Comment: @bakunin Ja, sind sie.  Vor allem, da Anglizismen oft nicht eingedeutscht sind und von ihrer Phonetik fremd wirken.

Comment: @FUZxxl: "von ihrer Phonetik fremd" wirken "Phonetik" (Fonetik?) oder "katexochen" auch, also sollten nach der Logik auch alle Gräzismen verschwinden, oder? Oder gibt es da ein System (Süstem?), warum man seine Selbstbewegten meistens mit Viertopfvierbummszerknalltreiblingen ausstattet? Andererseits ist natürlich "ich finds häßlich" eine allgemein anerkannte linguistische Kategorie, da sollte man für das Fachvokabular bei Berechnern keine Ausnahme machen.

Comment: @bakunin Ja ich weiß auch nicht so genau wie man das beschreiben kann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a bit difficult to translate this kind of thing, but here's how I understand they should be translated:

- A type is called **Typ** or **Datentyp** (e.g. Bool)
- In order to distinguish primitive from compound types, they're also called **Elementare Datentypen**
- A type containing other types is called a **Container** or **Abstrakter Datentyp** (e.g List)
- A compound type / composite from primitive types is called **Verbund** (e.g. Struct [Struktur])
- A Type of a Type is called **Art** (kind)
- Types of the `*` kind are called **Grundtypen**
- Types of the `a -> b` kind are called **Konstruktoren** or **Typkonstruktoren**, where a and b are kinds, or **Arten**.

  If you combine them into classes, they're called **Typkonstruktorklassen** (e.g. Functor)
- The element type is just called **Elementtyp**, the index type is just **Indextyp**.

This is from a Haskell class. Of course professors choose to call them different things, and since they are often newly coined, or seldom translated, there might not be an entirely correct answer. You can only gauge their correctness on usage. Even english usage varies from time to time.

By inference, and because I can't find any reference to a German translation:

- Sorts should be called **Artentypen**

In english, they're often just called "types of Kinds", rather than "sorts", so, I'll just assert that **Artentypen** is as correct as any other term. Most importantly: it will be understood properly. Note: "Typenarten" would mean "kinds of types".

These articles might contain some useful words to borrow:

- [Kategorientheorie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorientheorie)
- [Funktionale Programmierung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funktionale_Programmiersprache)
- [Typinferenz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typinferenz)

Comment: *Art* sounds good. How about sorts (types of kinds)?

Comment: @FUZxxl I think I've found a reasonable translation for that too. But it's my own, without any reference to it. And a google search for "Artentypen" yields no relevant results. Use with care. :)

Comment: Than we could as well say "Typtypen" for kinds and "Typtypentypen" for sorts :-)

Comment: Good call. There's way to little humour in type theory papers anyway. :)

Comment: What do you think about using *Gattung*, thus following the biological taxonomy for animals?

Comment: *Gattung* could be quite confusing I think. People already use "Ordnung" and "Klasse" to mean somewhat different concepts. You should always coin terms as conservatively as possible, and Artentypen works because it explains itself. Some of the translations in computer science are very awkward indeed: Think of the world *Instanz (ein Objekt ist eine Instanz einer Klasse)*: It's been translated literally, and the result is a word which is pretty much wrong. Yet the "correct" term (*Exemplar*) is just not used in the the real world. In short: stick to words people are familiar with, in context.

Answer (score 0):

In der Mathematik ist das vorsetzen des Präfixes Meta die übliche Form um zur abstrakteren Ebene überzugehen. Das lässt sich auch wiederholt anwenden. Z.B. Metatyp, Metametatyp, usw.. Ich habe allerdings keine Ahnung, welcher Sprachgebrauch in der Typtheorie üblich ist.

Answer (score 0):

Aus meiner Sicht ist die Fragestellung etwas verwirrend. Nach meiner Interpretation zielt sie auf die sprachliche Unterscheidung zwischen sogenannten Basistypen und polymorphen Typen ab.

Man sollte sich hier veranschaulichen, dass die o. g. Phrasen dem Zweck dienen, die Abhängigkeit beziehungsweise Vererbungsstruktur zwischen Objekten zu spezifizieren. Die Mehrfachvererbung ist ein Versuch, "wirkliche" Objektrelationen programmatisch abzubilden.
Aus meiner Sicht wurden, um das Thema verständlicher zu gestalten, Hilfsbezeichnungen ("verhält sich wie", "ist ein", "kind of", "sort of" usw.) geschaffen, welche – falsch verstanden – mehr zur Verwirrung, denn zur Klärung der Sachverhalte beitragen.

Zur Lösung: Eine direkte Übersetzung der Bezeichnung ist ebenso möglich, wie die Reduktion auf eine direkte Beschreibung des Sachverhalts. Es gibt in diesem Fall keine Unterscheidung zwischen verschiedenen Ursprüngen der Relation.

- Ein Boot ist vom Typ Wasserfahrzeug/ ein Boot ist ein Erbe von Wasserfahrzeug/ ein Boot verhält sich wie ein Wasserfahrzeug.
- Ein Auto ist vom Typ Landfahrzeug/ ein Auto ist ein Erbe von Landfahrzeug/ ein Boot verhält sich wie ein Landfahrzeug.
- Ein Amphibienfahrzeug ist vom Typ Landfahrzeug und Wasserfahrzeug/ ein Amphibienfahrzeug ist ein Erbe von Landfahrzeug und von Wasserfahrzeug/ ein Amphibienfahrzeug verhält sich wie ein Landfahrzeug und wie ein Wasserfahrzeug.

Ausschlaggebend ist hierbei, dass zur Beschreibung die Begrifflichkeiten gewählt werden, welche optimal zu dem Kontext der Darstellung passen.

Comment: Hm... anscheinend war meine Beschreibung doch etwas verwirrend. Ich habe nicht über OO-Programmierung gesprochen. Es geht um Typen, wie man sie in funktionalen Sprachen (z.B. Haskell) findet. Weil diese parametrisiert werden können (ähnlich wie Templates in C++ und Generics in Java), muss man angegeben können, welche Art von Paramatrisierung nötig ist. Dies nennt man dann auf Englisch *kind*. z.B. hat `Bool` kind `*` (kein Parameter= und `Maybe` kind `* -> *` (ein Parameter). Meine Frage bezog sich auf dies und die Typen von kinds (auf Englisch *sorts*)... Ich hoffe, es ist jetzt klarer.

Comment: Oh - vielleicht hab ich das auch falsch verstanden. Im allgemeinen spricht man dann aber nur noch von generischen Typen. Hier ist allerdings der Kontext sehr wichtig, was versuchst du denn zu beschreiben?

Comment: Ich möchte meine Facharbeit fürs Abitur über das Hindley-Milner-Typsystem schreiben, wo ich mich auch mit solchen Typen und "Typtypen" auseinandersetze. Weil diese in Deutsch geschrieben werden muss, habe ich überlegt, wie man dazu sagt.

Comment: Aus meiner Sicht bleibt die Verwendung verschiedener Begriffe für den gleichen Sachverhalt der unnötige Gebrauch von Synonymen. Ich verweise zu dem Thema auf : http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~psteffen/atfp04/Typsystem_und_Typinferenz.pdf und http://www.fh-wedel.de/~si/seminare/ss02/Ausarbeitung/2.types/typhas1.html

Comment: Ich weiß, dass *type*, *kind* und *sort* eigentlich Synonyme sind. In ihrer Verwendung in Haskell haben diese aber durchaus unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Wie schon mehrfachgesagt, ein *type* typisiert Variablen, während ein *kind* einen *type* typisiert und ein *sort* ein *kind* typisiert. Das ist nicht bloß die Verwendung von Synonymen für den gleichen Sachverhalt. Es ist Vergleichbar mit der Taxonomie von Lebewesen, wo eigentlich recht ähnliche Begriffe verschiedene Ebenenen charakterisieren.